# Query strange behaviour. Google App Engine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a model like this:

```
class Group(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  description = db.TextProperty()
```

Sometimes when executing queries like:

```
groups = Group.all().order("name").fetch(20)
```

or

```
groups = Group.all()
```

I'm getting error massages like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 501, in __call__
handler.get(*groups)
File "/home/al/Desktop/p/mwr-dev/main.py", line 638, in get
groups = Group.all()
AttributeError: type object 'Group' has no attribute 'all'
```

But when I'm using GQL queries with the same meaning, everything goes fine.

Why does that happens? I'm don't getting why GAE thinks that 'all' is attribute?

---

UPDATE:
 Oops ... I've found out that I also had request handler named the same as model ;(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`all` is indeed an attribute (specifically an executable one, a method) but as Group inherits from Model it should have that attribute; clearly something strange is going on, for example the name Group at the point does not refer to the object you think it does. I suggest putting a `try` / `except AttributeError, e:` around your `groups = Group.all()` call, and in the `except` branch emit (e.g. by logging) all possible information you can find about `Group`, including what `__bases__` it actually has, its `dir()`, and so forth.

This is about how far one can go in trying to help you (diagnosing that something very weird must have happened to the name `Group` and suggesting how to pinpoint details) without seeing your many hundreds of lines of code that could be doing who-knows-what to that name!-).